# Spring MVC Ajax 406 bad request

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I have these links about this error still my problem is not solving.[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840149/spring-mvc-ajax-400-bad-request), [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744307/spring-mvc-400-bad-request-ajax), I have checked some more but they were based on json.

First of All i tell you that the same code is working in my another project the thing is that i have implement that project in jsp and serlvets and this one in spring and hibernate.

The thing is that request comes to the method. when it returns. A message comes in console 400 bad request.

this is my method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/populateBillItems")
public @ResponseBody List<String> populateItems(@RequestParam String catName) {
    itemNames = productService.getItemNames(catName);
    return itemNames;
}
```

Javascript

```
function populateItems(obj){
    var itemCategory = obj.value;
    $.get('populateBillItems', {
        catName : itemCategory
    }, function(response) {

        var select = $('#itemName');
        select.find('option').remove();
        $.each(response, function(index, value) {
            $('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo(select);
        });
   });
}
```

In debug mode i get the following result in eclipse
[image: Debug]

You can see the that values are retrieved from database but when the response is returned this error comes in console

```
 GET   http://localhost:8080/InventoryManagementSystemUsingSpring/populateBillItems?catName=Rice 406 (Not Acceptable)
```

This is the first Problem.

I have another function in jquery which send request to controller and get id and populate it in a textfield. It also gives the same error as the above one is giving..

```
 function populateBillId(obj){
    var objValue=obj.value;
    var table="";
    if(objValue=='Borrower'){
        table="BorrowerBill";
        alert(table);
        $("#customerName").prop("readonly", true);
    }else if(objValue=='Customer'){
        $("#customerName").prop("readonly",false);
        table="CustomerBill";
    }
    $.get('populateBillId', {
        tableName : table
    }, function(response) {
        var id=response;
        $("#billId").val(id);
    });
 }


GET http://localhost:8080/InventoryManagementSystemUsingSpring/populateBillId?tableName=BorrowerBill
```

Headers:
    [image]

The Problem is almost solved. Now i am getting the values I have made my reponse method like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/populateBillItems")
public @ResponseBody String populateItems(@RequestParam String catName) {
    itemNames = productService.getItemNames(catName);
    String json=null;
    json = new Gson().toJson(itemNames);
    return json;
}
```

and modeified JQuery like this

```
 function populateItems(obj){
var itemCategory = obj.value;
$.get('populateBillItems', {
    catName : itemCategory
}, function(response) {

var select = $('#itemName');
select.find('option').remove();
  $.each(JSON.parse(response, function(index, value){
  $('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo(select);
   }));
 });
}
```

But now problem is that i also getting (double quotations)"" in the options

These are the quotations in itemNames SelectBox and Id Textfield

[image]

Comment: A 400 Bad Request error generally means that the properties the server received in the request caused an error. I would check in to what you're sending and what the server is doing with it. Your JS code is unlikely to be the issue (other than any missing input sanitisation), I would start by debugging the `productService.getItemNames` call.

Comment: The request is comming to the server and it even do actions on it. but after the method returns reponse, that message comes.

Comment: You can see that the result shows that items are retrieved from database. So i think there is no error in it.

Comment: Did you define `Consume` annotation for the path? It seems your service expects specific `Content-Type` header

Comment: add your pom.xml file also !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your operation did not fail.

I saw that you reveived a `HTTP 406` message.

Your backend service is saying that the response type it is returning is not provided in the Accept HTTP header in your Client request.

JSON is served as `application/json`. You should add this to your header.

[w3.org - 10.4.7 -  406 Not Acceptable](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

**EDIT:**

At the moment in your method you give a String back to the frontend. Try to convert the json like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/populateBillItems")
public @ResponseBody String populateItems(@RequestParam String catName) {
    itemNames = productService.getItemNames(catName);
    String json = new Gson().toJson(itemNames);
    System.out.println(json); // result before parsing
    json = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsString();
    System.out.println(json); // result after parsing
    return json;
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question the problem is almost solved.

Comment: @MuhammadDanishKhan can you show your double quotations string/json in your question.

Comment: Ok i'm adding the picture

Comment: @MuhammadDanishKhan thanks, but is it also possible to show the string/json as it comes.

Comment: I have tried that one but it gives error like undefined in [values]

Comment: @MuhammadDanishKhan I updated my answer. Check if it helps you